# Titanium Appcelerator (Alloy): I want to add and delete from tableview

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

i fill data in the textfield when i press done on android keyboard it will enter the data in the tableviewrow but i dont know how?
i did it on button click

and second question is : i want to delete the data on button click whose
row has

```
hasCheck=true
```

[i mean to say these rows on button click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpSkT.png)
 index.xml

```
    <TableView id="table">
        <TableViewRow title="Capsicum" onClick="select"></TableViewRow>
        <TableViewRow title="Beans" onClick="select"></TableViewRow>
        <TableViewRow title="Spinach" onClick="select"></TableViewRow>
        <TableViewRow title="Pizza" onClick="select"></TableViewRow>
        <TableViewRow title="Burger" onClick="select"></TableViewRow>
    </TableView>
    <TextField id="textfield" class="insertField" hintText="Add ingredients"></TextField>
    <Button id="addButton" title="Add" onClick="addRow" ></Button>
    <Button id="removeButton" title="Remove" onClick="removeRow" ></Button>
</Window>
```

index.js file

```
    function addRow(){
    var myTextFieldValue = $.textfield.getValue();
    var row=Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({title:myTextFieldValue});
    $.table.appendRow(row);
}


        function select(e) {
        if (e.row.hasCheck) {
            e.row.hasCheck = false;
        } else {
            e.row.hasCheck= true;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple if you properly follow the Appc Docs:

**Answer for Query 1:**

There's an event called **[return](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TextField-event-return)** for TextField proxies which is called when you press Done button or Return button on iOS or Android. But the title of this Return button can be anything as specified here: **[Return Key Title](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TextField-property-returnKeyType)**

So, you have to make below changes in **TextField** node to make it work on pressing enter on keyboard, like this:

```
<TextField id="textfield" returnKeyType="Ti.UI.RETURNKEY_DONE" onReturn="addRow" class="insertField" hintText="Add ingredients" />
```

---

---

**Answer for Query 2:**

You will have to fetch all rows from table which is a bit lengthy because you cannot directly fetch rows from TableView, rather you will first need to fetch the first section of TableView & then rows from section.

***Note:*** If you do not add any section in TableView, then by default Titanium adds a single section in TableView and add rows in this section. This is why you need to take care of getting the first section first.

Here's the code to delete all checked-rows on Remove button click.

```
function removeRow() {
    // first get all sections of table which will be first section in your case
    var sections = $.table.sections;

    // perform this check to make your code error free when there are no rows added to tableview.
    if (sections.length !== 0) {
        var rows = sections[0].rows;
        var totalRows = rows.length;

        if (totalRows !== 0) {
            // now delete all rows which has uncheck=true
            for (var i=0; i<totalRows; i++) {
                var tempCurrentRow = rows[i];
                if (tempCurrentRow.hasCheck) {
                    $.table.deleteRow(tempCurrentRow);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Just a minor change in your adding code so that you don't accidentally add empty title rows:

```
function addRow(){
   var myTextFieldValue = $.textfield.value.trim();
   if (myTextFieldValue != "") {
      $.table.appendRow( Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({title:myTextFieldValue}) );
   }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for the first query help.. but second query is not working i create a select function in which i have hascheck i.e     
 `function select(e) {
 if (e.row.hasCheck) {
  e.row.hasCheck = false;
 } else {
  e.row.hasCheck= true;
 }
 
}`   but when i apply your code it is not deleting any row

Comment: See my updated answer. I missed to add **sections[0].rows;** in **removeRow** method. It will work now.

Comment: It helped me alot Thankyou so much sir

Comment: If my answer has solved your question, then mark my answer as "accepted" to let other users know about the solution.